Issue in Converging a FCC Pd crystal on VASP, errors in body text
I have been struggling optimizing a specific structure in VASP. But I keep getting errors, and it only runs for like 3 seconds. These are a few errors I get. Sometimes it doesn't have the final one listed, but it does most of the time, but they aren't all listed at the end they happen in different spots which is why I also attached a screen shot.

WARNING: Sub-Space-Matrix is not hermitian in DAVere

BRMIX: very serious problems
the old and the new charge density differ

ERROR FEXCP: supplied Exchange-correletion table



I have tried changing my POTNIM from 0.05 down to 0.01. I have also tried IBRION = 3, 2, 1. There are quite a few posts on the VASP forum and here about each of these issues, but they don't seem to work. My structure should be really close since it's from a crystal data base, so I don't think it's because my initial structure is too off. I am wondering if FCC structures optimize differently from slabs. I have only optimized slabs with molecules absorbed on top with this INCAR file (and they work fine), but maybe FCC structures need a different consideration since they are much smaller? Below are my POSCAR and INCAR files.

INCAR
System = Pd structure

PREC  = ACCURATE

ISTART = 0 

ICHARG = 2 

ENCUT = 500

ISMEAR = 0

SIGMA = 0.09

EDIFF = 1E-5

EDIFFG = -0.05

NELM = 100

NELMIN = 2

NSW = 400

ALGO = FAST

IBRION = 3 

ISIF = 2

POTIM = 0.05 #step size

MAXMIX=12  #reuse the mixer between ionic steps; save time

ISPIN = 1

GGA = PE #Perdew-Burke-Ernzerof

IVDW = 12 #Dispersion: D3-BJ

LWAVE = .FALSE.

LCHARG = .FALSE.

NCORE = 64


POSCAR
Pd Crystal
1.0
       3.9579999447         0.0000000000         0.0000000000
       0.0000000000         3.9579999447         0.0000000000
       0.0000000000         0.0000000000         3.9579999447
   Pd
   4
Direct
    0.000000000         0.000000000         0.000000000
    0.000000000         0.500000000         0.500000000
    0.500000000         0.000000000         0.500000000
    0.500000000         0.500000000         0.000000000 


For this file after much trial and error, all it took was switching my NCORE to a lower number. Switching it down from NCORE= 64 to NCORE = 2 fixed the problem and allowed it to run.
I don't necessarily know why, so if there is someone who could explain why I would be appreciate it!
